# How to make choice between NoSQL and SQL?

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb, express, nosql

My question is that I want to learn nodejs/express, and make a super simple web project. It would be a database with tables : users, video_games, categories.

The web site will just show list of games (just an example).

In this typical case, what would be more efficient : Mysql or MongoDB (SQL or NoSql) ?

Comment: In this case both should work just fine.

Comment: If it is excessive read and writes on DB then go for NoSQL like MongoDB, but in case if it just simple and light then use SQL like MySQL.

Comment: Thank you @fvu so it means there is some cases where it would be impossible to use NoSql (i'm really new : i'm starting now)

Comment: Impossible? No. Harder, or less optimal, yes.

Comment: @AnkurSoni I'd never use IO load as a deciding factor: "excessive reads and writes" can be solved with a properly tuned database instance, things like referential integrity etc are much more difficult to retrofit.

Comment: @fvu: you are right, there are several parameters that makes nosql different from SQL , hence question marked on hold. I randomly gave just 1 point.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case were you want to show only list ( you don't want to actual store videos, doc, texy, etc..) SQL database will be a good choice.

Another reason to use SQL database is that your data is relational ( I am assuming that the data i.e video_games, category...etc are linked to users) were SQL database suits more.

You should go to nosql database only when there is to relationship between your data ( well this is not the only case, but for beginners were your aim is to simply pick the right database this suffice)

Comment: Ok I see, but what if some day i'll decide to put real games (for example) and by clicking on games on list it will download them ?

Comment: In that case also SQL database will work fine.

Comment: Ok so thank you sir

Comment: Finally I decided to use NodeJS, expressJS and Sql, good combinaison ?

Comment: @Mitch, yes go ahead !!